# google-api-java-client create an unlisted map

Tags: maps, gdata-java-client

I can create a map using the google-api-java-client with the current 1.47.1 version of the API.

However, all the maps are "Public". How can I create one so it shows as "Unlisted" ?

API used;
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/

Sample create map code from project;
code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/maps/CreateMap.java

Example of map viewed via maps.google.com (note the Public/Unlisted setting)
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BwU8YHq384cgNzBFUXJHSmU1REE

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "create a map" and "Unlisted" ? Which API(s), if any, are you trying to communicate with?

Comment: I'm using the java client library; http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/
The sample for create map is here;
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/maps/CreateMap.java
When you go into My Maps via a browser, you can click "public" or "unlisted" next to each map. I want to set this via the API.

Comment: Oh, I missed that you were talking about the GData client library. Are you sure that this option is even exposed via the API? I couldn't find any documentation that indicated that it was.